# Setting outer class instance to null, and yet inner class instances is able to access outer class's field. How?

Tags: java, nested, closures, inner-classes

Consider the following piece of code:

```
class OuterClass{
    String ocs="ocs";
    class InnerClass{
        String ics="ics";
        void innerMeth(){
            System.out.println(ocs);
        }
    }
}
//main class
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args){
        OuterClass ob=new OuterClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass ob1=ob.new InnerClass();
        ob=null;
        ob1.innerMeth();
    }
}
```

Still prints out string 'ocs' .
basically even though I have set `OuterClass` instance to null.
`InnerClass` instance can still access the `OuterClass` reference's field `ocs`
How ?

Is this something to do with closures ?? i.e maintaining the variables in context even after the context is no more, in this case the `OuterClass` object.

Comment: An instance cannot be null. That's not a concept that exists. A variable can store the value `null`. That does not affect any other reference to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `finalize()` method to each class will give a better understanding.

```
 class OuterClass {
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("oc instance finalized..");
    };
    String ocs = "ocs";

class InnerClass {
    String ics = "ics";

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("IC instance finalized");
    };

    void innerMeth() {
        System.out.println(ocs);
    }
}
```

}

```
// main class
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OuterClass ob = new OuterClass();
        OuterClass.InnerClass ob1 = ob.new InnerClass();
        ob = null;
        // ob1=null;
        System.gc();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ob1.innerMeth(); // you will get NPE here
    }
}
```

When only `ob` is set to `null`,`ob1` still has a reference to it, so it will not be finalized, and hence is still accessible.

If you set `ob` as well as `ob1` to `null`, then the output will be :

```
 IC instance finalized
oc instance finalized..
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at HelloWorld.main
```

because there will be no references to either `ob` or `ob1` hence both objects are `finalized`. Note that it is the *reference* that is set to null. Other references might be still pointing to the object along with `ob` (in your case `ob1`)

Comment: We all will have this kind of moment at times :)

Answer (score 2):

InnerClass sotres its own reference to the outer class when its created. If you null the reference to the outer class this does not concern the reference the inner class maintains. See [the java language ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> An instance i of a direct inner class C of a class O is associated with an instance of O, known as the immediately enclosing instance of i. The immediately enclosing instance of an object, if any, is determined when the object is created (§15.9.2).

Answer (score 2):

All you are updating is a reference to an instance, not an instance itself. A reference is just a thing that points to something else.

Think of it like the Contacts in your phone - you are storing your friends' phone numbers so that you can call their phone; deleting their number from your contacts doesn't make their phone disappear.

Comment: Well yes, its important to remember 'reference variable' == 'instance' itself !